# Javascript Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression when renaming

Tags: javascript

I have some code which is giving me the following error when I rename a class name.

This gives no error:

```
this.container = document.createElement("ul"),
```

But when I rename the container class name to this:

```
this.tt-container = document.createElement("ul"),
```

I get the following error:

Syntax error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression

How can I fix this?

Comment: If `-` were valid for a variable name, then how would you resolve the expression `x-y` - is it subtraction or is retrieving a value from a single variable? And if you say "well, no spaces, therefore it's a variable", then what about `x - y` - isn't this now three variables separated by a space?

Comment: "*when I rename a class name*" - what does your code have to do with class names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties),

> **An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation.**

In your case `-` is not a valid JavaScript identifier. To use `-`, Use *Bracket Notation*

`this["tt-container"] = document.createElement("ul"),`

Answer (score 1):

use _ instead of -, so `this.tt_container`, not `this.tt-container`